# Trouble using Applescript in ApplescriptObjc Xcode project

Tags: xcode, applescript, applescript-objc

I'm very new to Applescript-ObjC and am trying to do something pretty simple. I have this applescript app that I've been using to convert text to Title Case and ALL CAPS. The app works great. But when I try to bring it into the Xcode AppDelegate.applescript and attach it to buttons on the UI, nothing happens. I ran the 'Build' without errors but it simple doesn't do anything when I open the app and click the buttons.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

(BTW this script is from http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=42284#p42284)

```
script AppDelegate
property parent : class "NSObject"
-- IBOutlets

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_


on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_

############# My Buttons #############

-- Title Case --

on clickTitleCase_(sender)
    set someText to the clipboard

    set newCase to (changeCase of someText to "title") (* "upper", "lower", "sentence", "capitalized" or "title" *)

    set the clipboard to newCase
end clickTitleCase_

-- All CAPS --

on clickALLCAPs_(sender)
    set someText to the clipboard

    set newCase to (changeCase of someText to "upper") (* "upper", "lower", "sentence", "capitalized" or "title" *)

    set the clipboard to newCase
end clickALLCAPs_

############# Text Conversion Handlers #############

property lowerStr : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzáàâäãåæçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõōøœúùûüÿ"
property upperStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÀÂÄÃÅÆÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕŌØŒÚÙÛÜŸ"
property alphaList : lowerStr's characters & reverse of upperStr's characters
property sentenceBreak : {".", "!", "?"}
property wordBreak : {space, ASCII character 202, tab}
property everyBreak : wordBreak & sentenceBreak
property whiteSpace : wordBreak & {return, ASCII character 10}
property currList : missing value
property sentenceModList : {"i", "i'm", "i’m", "i've", "i’ve", "I’ve", "I've", "I’m", "I'm", "I"} (* could be extended to include certain proper nouns, acronyms, etc. *)
property mixedModList : {"A", "For", "So", "An", "In", "The", "And", "Nor", "To", "At", "Of", "Up", "But", "On", "Yet", "By", "Or", "Usa", "Nasa", "Hiv", "Aids", "Vs", "Pm", "Wef", "Wwf", "Nsx", "NSX", "WWF", "WEF", "PM", "vs", "AIDS", "HIV", "NASA", "USA", "or", "by", "yet", "on", "but", "up", "of", "at", "to", "nor", "and", "the", "in", "an", "so", "for", "a"}

on textItems from currTxt
    tell (count currTxt's text items) to if it > 4000 then tell it div 2 to return my (textItems from (currTxt's text 1 thru text item it)) & my (textItems from (currTxt's text from text item (it + 1) to -1))
    currTxt's text items
end textItems

on initialCap(currTxt)
    tell currTxt to if (count words) > 0 then tell word 1's character 1 to if it is in lowerStr then
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to it
    tell my (textItems from currTxt) to return beginning & upperStr's character ((count lowerStr's text item 1) + 1) & rest
end if
currTxt
end initialCap

to capItems from currTxt against breakList
repeat with currBreak in breakList
    set text item delimiters to currBreak
    if (count currTxt's text items) > 1 then
        set currList to my (textItems from currTxt)
        repeat with n from 2 to count currList
            set my currList's item n to initialCap(my currList's item n)
        end repeat
        set text item delimiters to currBreak's contents
        tell my currList to set currTxt to beginning & ({""} & rest)
    end if
end repeat
currTxt
end capItems

on modItems from currTxt against modList
    set currList to modList
    set currCount to (count modList) div 2
    repeat with currBreak in everyBreak
        set text item delimiters to currBreak
        if (count currTxt's text items) > 1 then repeat with n from 1 to currCount
        set text item delimiters to my currList's item n & currBreak
        if (count currTxt's text items) > 1 then
            set currTxt to textItems from currTxt
            set text item delimiters to my currList's item -n & currBreak
            tell currTxt to set currTxt to beginning & ({""} & rest)
        end if
    end repeat
end repeat
currTxt
end modItems

to changeCase of currTxt to caseType
if (count currTxt's words) is 0 then return currTxt

ignoring case
    tell caseType to set {upper_Case, lower_Case, sentence_Case, capitalized_Case, title_Case} to {it is "upper", it is "lower", it is "sentence", it is "capitalized", it is "title"}
end ignoring

if not (upper_Case or lower_Case or capitalized_Case or sentence_Case or title_Case) then
    error "The term \"" & caseType & "\" is not a valid case type option. Please use \"upper\", \"lower\", \"sentence\", \"title\" or \"mixed\"."
    else if upper_Case then
    set n to 1
    else
    set n to -1
end if

considering case
    set tid to text item delimiters

    repeat with n from n to n * (count lowerStr) by n
        set text item delimiters to my alphaList's item n
        set currTxt to textItems from currTxt
        set text item delimiters to my alphaList's item -n
        tell currTxt to set currTxt to beginning & ({""} & rest)
    end repeat

    if sentence_Case then
        set currTxt to initialCap(modItems from (capItems from currTxt against sentenceBreak) against sentenceModList)
        else if capitalized_Case or title_Case then
        set currTxt to initialCap(capItems from currTxt against whiteSpace)
        if title_Case then set currTxt to initialCap(capItems from (modItems from currTxt against mixedModList) against sentenceBreak)
    end if

    set text item delimiters to tid
end considering
currTxt
end changeCase

end script
```

Comment: General recommendation: chuck all that crappy ASCII-only case-changing code and use `(current application's NSString's stringWithString_(theText)'s uppercaseString()) as text` (or `lowercaseString`/`capitalizedString` as appropriate). While still not perfect (case is extremely tricky for machines to get perfectly correct since they know nothing about proper nouns and stuff), using `NSString` is far simpler and faster, supports Unicode, and is just way better at this sort of thing than any amateur AppleScript code will ever be.

Comment: I've tried that method but I prefer this script because it preserves punctuation. I

Comment: I'm not aware of -[NSString uppercaseString], etc. stripping punctuation. If they did, that would be a serious bug. Got examples?

Comment: @OP: Do yourself a favour, buy the book you can find in the lower right corner here: <http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/index.html>

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that book a try. I've been trying to do things with only a basic knowledge of Applescript and no significant knowledge of Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the above posters' suggestions, I was able to use `NSString uppercaseString` to solve this problem:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set aPhrase to "this is 'a' test phrase with 'punctuation'"
its makeTitleCase(aPhrase)

on makeTitleCase(stringOfText)
    set makeLowerCaseList to {"A", "For", "So", "An", "In", "The", "And", "Nor", "To", "At", "Of", "Up", "But", "On", "Yet", "By", "Or"}
    set theString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:stringOfText
    set theString to (theString's capitalizedString())
    set stringOfText to theString as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
    set listOfWords to text items of stringOfText
    set listOfWords to listOfWords as list
    repeat with x from 2 to count of listOfWords -- item 2 because per APA Style the first word is capitalized irregardless
        set targetItem to (item x of listOfWords)
        set aString to (" " & targetItem & " ")
        set theWord to words of aString as list
        repeat with y from 1 to count of makeLowerCaseList
            set origWord to (item 1 of theWord) as text
            set compareWord to (item y of makeLowerCaseList) as text
            if origWord = compareWord then
                set oneWord to (current application's NSString's stringWithString:(item x of listOfWords))
                set item x of listOfWords to (oneWord's lowercaseString) as text
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    return listOfWords as text
end makeTitleCase


on makeALLCAPS(stringOfText)
    set theString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:stringOfText
    set theString to (theString's uppercaseString())
    set stringOfText to theString as text
    return stringOfText
end makeALLCAPS
```